# what's wrong with this code? It's seems to be ok but my school auto feedback says it can't run it

Tags: python, debugging

```
def last_early(check_str):

    x = check_str.count(check_str[-1])

    if( x > 1):
        valid = True
    else:
        valid = False
    return valid

my_str = input("enter str: ")
my_str = my_str.lower()

valid = last_early(my_str)
print(valid)
```

the question is: "The function accepts as a string parameter. The function returns "true" if the character that appears last in the string also appears earlier. Otherwise, false will be printed"

Comment: when `check_str` is empty string i.e. `''`, you would get `IndexError`. Maybe you are failing this edge test-case.

Comment: FWIW, you could shorten it to `return check_str.count(check_str[-1]) > 1`, though personally I would write it as `last = check_str[-1]; return check_str.count(last) > 1`. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when `check_str` is empty string i.e. `''`, you would get `IndexError`. Maybe you are failing this edge test-case.

-- [comment](/questions/66509137/whats-wrong-with-this-code-its-seems-to-be-ok-but-my-school-auto-feedback-say#comment117575547_66509137) by [Ch3steR](/users/12416453/ch3ster)

To see if this is the problem, try adding a guard clause for the empty string:

```
def last_early(check_str):
    if not check_str:
        return False

    ...
```